# href parameter : scriplet result truncated at first white space in a jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp, scriptlet

I use this scriplet code in a jsp, it's a huge and old webapp so we don't have enough time to make it with taglib etc.

```
buffer.append("<TD> <b><A href= ...title="+MCode.getMessage(sMillesime, true) +">"
```

The problem is that the variable is truncated at first whitespace, html generated for "test blabla" message is :

```
<TD> <b> <a href = ... title="test" blabla>
```

So only the first word is in the bubble. Any idea?

Comment: Did you try escaping value for title? Like: `title=\"" + MCode ... + "\">"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```
buffer.append("<TD> <b><A href= ...title=\""+MCode.getMessage(sMillesime, true) +"\">")
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a try:

```
title=\""+MCode.getMessage(sMillesime, true) +"\" >"
```